# writing a query in access that allows the user to select a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working with an access database which has a number of tables which hold similar information from different years.  I need to store the old information and so I cannot simply update the table every year.  How can I write a query which lets me pick which of these tables I want to run it on each time I run it?

Comment: Why can't you store all the records in a single table?

Comment: I think that will work.  Sorry for the silly question, I'm pretty new to access.